# how to configure Apache localhost server to access it from other computer

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, localhost

how can i access Apache localhost server of Ubuntu computer from other computer.
This computers are connected in same workplace by LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use private IP of that particular machine.
type `ifconfig` in server where you have installed nginx and copy the `inet` ip address.
now in remote machine under the same LAN , provide the IP address in browser.